# Lambda Function Inconsistently Missing DynamoDB Triggers

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

Perhaps I have a misunderstanding of something, but I have a Lambda function that is triggered by new items being added to a DynamoDB table.  My trigger is configured like so;

**DynamoDB Table Name:** My Table

**Batch Size**: 100

**Starting Position:** Latest

My function's code parses out any events that are not INSERT, and for the most part, this is functioning well.  I am noticing, however, that some of my new records will occasionally not trigger the Lambda function (I update the record with a `completed` tag when the function has run).  I can not find any rhyme or reason as to why, but wondering if I'm missing what the Batch Size is (I want every new record to trigger the function to run, as my users will be publishing individual records to the table).

Is this common behavior or is there more I could share to learn what could be causing this?

Comment: can you please provide a sample of the code you use to process it, maybe there is a bug there? every row should be being sent via the DB stream... have you logged at your cloudwatch logs for the function?

Comment: there should be a code bug.

Comment: Thanks for replying!  Each row added to my table has a unique identifier; when I search CloudWatch, the functions that do not run do not appear in CloudWatch at all.  It is as though it simply "skips" records being added altogether.